# How can i be sure a file is kept on IPFS

Tags: ipfs

I want to understand how media files on NFT works.

If i store a media file as a blob in a smart-contract's storage value, i will be sure the file will be kept forever on Ethereum blockchain. But it will cost a lot of GAS (and GAS is very expensive !)

Some people are storing the media file on IPFS. Here is what i have understood about IPFS:

- There are several IPFS nodes in the world. Everybody can create an IPFS node.
- Ethereum nodes are ALL connected each others. This is not the case for IPFS nodes.
- I can store a file on an IPFS node. The node will give me a hash which identifies the file.
- I can ask the IPFS node with the hash. The node will give me my file.
- The file will be automatically deleted if the hash is not often asked.
- If a node doesn't know the hash, it will ask other nodes. But the nodes are not all connected. The file might be on another node which is unknowned.
- If another node can give the file to the first node. This one will keep a copy of the file.

Am I true at this step ?

Do you agree about this system is not perfect because i have no warranty my file will be kept for years. I have learned how works NFT. And a lot of NFT are working with IPFS. Everybody says the media files will be kept safety but i think this is not true. Do you agree with that ?

I have read Filecoin is a crypto currency associated to IPFS. When i store a file on an IPFS node, i have to pay Filecoin. But how can i be sure the node won't be shutdowned after paying ? When a node keep a copy of a file provided by another node: Which node earns Filecoin in this case ?

Thanks

Comment: With ipfs you can pin files, see here https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/pin-files/#pin-files-using-ipfs.

Comment: I have read about pinning files but this is the same problem